# Problem with \volcite and variants from biblatex after MikTeX update (biblatex 3.15)

Tags: biblatex, biber

After my latest MikTeX update (November 2020) I have witnessed several issues when compiling files that compiled before the update. These were mostly related to the biblatex or the babel packages. I have been able to sort some of them, but the following MWE won't compile on my Windows 10 system. (Please note the comment inside the `document` environment.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{bibtest.bib}
  @MvBook{Theory,
    author = {Someone},
    title = {Theory},
    volumes = {2},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bibtest.bib}

\begin{document}

  \volcite{1}[11]{Theory}
  % If the optional argument is removed, the file compiles.  
  %\volcite{1}{Theory}

\end{document}
```

More precisely, the first compilation works and it is after running Biber and compiling for the second time that it fails. In my case, it gets stuck while loading the file `english.lbx` from `biblatex`. How can this issue be solved?

Comment: it works with the dev version of biblatex 1.6. you can get it here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/development/

Comment: Problem solved? Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

This was a bug (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1039) in `biblatex` 3.15 that was resolved in the version 3.16 (released 2020-12-31).
It was caused by using field format aliases too eagerly, which lead to an infinite loop.

Update your TeX system to get `biblatex` v3.16 and a matching Biber version.

---

### Old answer

While you wait for the release of version 3.16 you can fix the issue by providing the appropriate definition for the field format `volcitepages` in the preamble

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \volcite{1}[11]{knuth:ct}
\end{document}
```